# AWS Athena Query Editor keeps defaulting to 'white background' with black text

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I recently logged into my AWS Athena Query console and I am now no longer able to change the default background of my query editor. I am using the primary workgroup of my organization and am the only one that has encountered this problem. [White Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnrQW.png)

I have tried to change the default color scheme of my editor and of the Workgroup (dark/light theme), but that seems to make no difference. The editor successfully changes to a different theme but I am still seeing white on black despite the browser or theme set. I recently connected my Athena tables to my PyCharm IDE. Could that have affected some configuration?

[Current Colour profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLC5y.png)

Has anyone else encountered this before? Could this be a bug with AWS or a configuration issue with my Workgroup?